# What is the difference between "renderTo: document.body" and " renderTo: Ext.getBody()" in extJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

When to use them and when not to?
And what theoretical differences do they have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> Returns the current document body as an Ext.Element.

By being wrapped in an Ext.Element instance, you can access other functionality as detailed here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element

For example you may want to add a mask using the mask() method with a message to the user whilst something is going on in the application.

document.body returns the pure body dom